# sql - what's the faster/better way to refer to columns in a where clause with inner joins?

Tags: sql, performance, syntax, inner-join, where-clause

Say I've got a query like this:

```
select table1.id, table1.name
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.name = "parent" and table2.status = 1
```

Is it true that, since there's an inner join, I can refer the table2's status column even from table1? Like this:

```
select table1.id, table1.name
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.name = "parent" and table1.status = 1
```

And if yes, what's the best of the two ways?

Comment: No, that only works if `table1` also has a `status`-column. However, it would likely contain different data. To elaborate, the table name is added to determine which of the tables in the `JOIN` contain the column (in case of the same column name occurring in multiple tables), or for readability's sake so it's instantly obvious where the data is coming from.

Comment: No, that's not true. Where did you get the idea that it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are asking that in an inner join, two fields of the same name, data type and length will be one field in the particular query. Technically that is not the case. Regardless of anything, `Table1.Status` will refer to `Table1` and `Table2.Status` will refer to `Table2`'s condition/value.

The two queries above CAN product different results from each other.

A good rule on this is that you stick your conditions on the base table, or `Table1`, in this case. If a field is exclusive to another table, that's when you'll use that Table's field.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not true. By Inner join what you are doing is say if you have table1 with m rows and table two with n rows then the third `SET` that will be produced by joining the two tables will have m*n rows based on match condition that you have mentioned in where clause. It's not m+n rows or infact columns of the two tables are not getting merged at database level. status column will remain in the table it has been defined.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can see this is not the case if you do

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT, name VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT, status INT);
```

Now if you run your second query you will get an error because you refer to t1.status, and the status column does not existing in table t1.

If there was a status field in both tables the query would run, but likely would not give the results you want e.g. assume status in table1 was always 1, and in table2 was always 0. Now your first query could never return rows, but your second one certainly could return rows.